# Sales at iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm just wondering how this comes:

[image]

So there are 3 units sold, but apparently just one of them was paid. Do you know why?
The screenshot was taken when having `Transaction type` activated.

Comment: So does it show discrepancy? 3 units on top, and 27 units at the bottom?

Comment: @sha: excuse me, I have no idea what you mean

Comment: Are these two screenshots part of one screen or you took them from different screens? When I go to this page in my portal - total number on top (3 in your case) matches sum of all numbers at the bottom (detail list, 25+2 in your case).

Comment: I can see that top one is for Dec 6 only, and bottom one for Nov 30 - Dec 7 period. So they don't rely to each other. Show us the bottom portion for Dec 6 only

Comment: @sha: I'm sorry for confusion, I uploaded a new screenshot, including both

Comment: I wonder if a free download is how it looks when a family member gets an app for free with Family Sharing for the app store. I don't know for sure, so I'll comment for now.

Comment: No. Did you change price on the app recently? Was it originally free?

Comment: @bmike: I think it will be shown as redownload.

Comment: @sha: yes I did, but shouldn't that change over night instead of in one day?

Comment: It might take some time to process and populate. So that might explain free downloads. Wait couple days and see how it will look again.

Comment: @sha so do you think the 2 free downloads might actually be paid downloads but they are displayed wrong? I will let you know in a few days :)

Comment: No. What I meant that two downloads happened before your price change took effect.

Comment: It actually is not the solution but since you took your time and explained it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following break-downs to see exact transactions. How much is your app price? [image]

[image]

As you can see only one paid version was sold. The other two were free.

Comment: The price is 1.99$

Comment: What do you see at the bottom of page when you select 'By Transaction Type'?

Comment: No change. Which transaction type shall I select?

Comment: When I select 'By Transaction Type' in my portal I can see breakdown by transactions. See updated answer. Do you see something similar?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Thought I shall use the filter. See the question for a screenshot of what I see.